# Loop through a dataframe: counting each pairwise combination of a value for each unique variable.

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, combinations

I have a dataframe called "df" like this:

```
ID  Value
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
3   a
3   b
3   e
3   f
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

I have a matrix filled with zeros like this:

```
  a b c d e f 
a x 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 x 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 x 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 x 0 0
e 0 0 0 0 x 0
f 0 0 0 0 0 x
```

I would then like to loop through the dataframe something like this:

```
for each ID, for each value i, for each value j != i, matrix[i,j] += 1
```

So for each ID, for each combination of values, I would like to raise the value in the matrix by 1, resulting in:

```
  a b c d e f 
a x 2 1 1 1 1
b 2 x 1 1 1 1
c 1 1 x 1 0 0
d 1 1 1 x 0 0
e 1 1 0 0 x 1
f 1 1 0 0 1 x
```

So for example, [a,b] = 2, because this combination of values occurs for two different IDs, while [a,c] = 1, because this combination of values only occurs when ID = 1 and not when ID = 3.

How can I achieve this? I already made a vector containing the unique IDs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be to get the `table` and then do a `crossprod`

```
out <- crossprod(table(df))
diag(out) <- NA #replace the diagonals with NA
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL #set the names of the dimnames as NULL
out
#   a  b  c  d  e  f
#a NA  2  1  1  1  1
#b  2 NA  1  1  1  1
#c  1  1 NA  1  0  0
#d  1  1  1 NA  0  0
#e  1  1  0  0 NA  1
#f  1  1  0  0  1 NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Value = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "e", "f")), .Names = c("ID", "Value"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```